# NS2 Dropped Packets

Tags: ns2

hello everyone : i got this results when i run AODV for 60 node for 600s area is 100X100 max speed 10m/s:
,generated packets == 95364,sent==95364,lost=112,dropped=112786,max delay=0.00899

is it true that the number of dropped packet  is greater than the generated one????
pls anyone can explain that???
if there is simulation wrong pls tell me .

another question what dropped packet exactly mean in NS2 ??? dose it contain the intermediate node dropped packet?

thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the code you have used to calculate above values?

Comment: its too long to be posted here , i can send it to your mail if you want.

Comment: It is not possible that dropped packet is greater than generated (send) packets. Check your script that you have to count the packets drop in AGT layer not in mac layer..

Answer (score 1):

You might calculate the retransmitting dropped packets because once a packet being dropped, mac layer retransmits the packet again.

Note: don't calculate the packet those dropped at the end of simulation, those with drop reason is 'END'

Answer (score 0):

In Network simulator 2 trace file generally;

Column 1 represents event type (s: send, r: receive, d: drop, f: forward)

Columns 2 and 3 provide time of the event.

Columns 4 to 7 provide next-hop information.

Columns 8 to 21 are called node property tags.

Column 11 gives the reason for a packet drop and the various reasons possible for a packet drop are as follows.

**END** drop due to end of simulation

**COL** drop due to collision at MAC layer

**DUP** drop due to duplicate packet

**ERR** drop due to MAC packet error

**RET** drop due to exceeding retry count

**STA** drop due to MAC invalid state

**BSY** drop due to MAC busy

**NRTE** drop due to no route available

**LOOP** drop due to routing loop

**TTL** drop due to TTL=0

**TOUT** drop due to packet expired

**IFQ** drop due to no buffer space in IFQ

**ARP** dropped ARP

**OUT** dropped by base stations

You may analyze your dropped packets by grouping them with the reasons.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible that dropped packet is greater than generated (send) packets. Check your script that you have to count the packets drop in AGT layer not in mac layer.

try to find the values using the below awk script.

```
BEGIN {

        sendLine = 0;

        recvLine = 0;

        fowardLine = 0;

        dropLine = 0;

}



$0 ~/^s.* AGT/ {

        sendLine ++ ;

}



$0 ~/^r.* AGT/ {

        recvLine ++ ;

}



$0 ~/^f.* RTR/ {

        fowardLine ++ ;

}


$0 ~/^D.* cbr/ {

        dropLine ++ ;

}

END {
printf "Packet Sent: %d\n,sendLine"
printf "Packet Received: %d\n,recvLine"
printf "Packet Drop: %d\n,dropLine"


        printf "PacketDelivery Ratio:%.4f \n",(recvLine/sendLine);
}
```

Comment: this code not working, ERROR-> 
awk: pkt2.awk:45: (FILENAME=2.tr FNR=952010) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
        `Packet Sent: %d
,sendLine'
                      ^ ran out for this one

Answer (score -1):

Well, you cannot drop more packets than you generate. Usually you drop them at the bottleneck queue, where they overflow the queue.